# Div hover is not working in every browser

Tags: html, css, hover

This is the page I am working with: https://books.fcostry.cz/

What I am trying to do is hide the searchbox (`.vc-searchbox`) on hover of the Books logo on the left upper side (`.vc-headerlogo`).

`.vc-headerlogo:hover .vc-searchbox{ display:none; }` is not working and I really don't know why.

I would like to do it using CSS but I am open to any solution. Thanks for any answer.

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mcve] first of all, and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Provide code instead of linking to somewhere else. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before you post

Comment: We also don't why it isn't working without seeing any CSS you have already tried. So add a code snippet of what you already have so we might be ablo to help you

Comment: _“is not working and I really don't know why”_ - because your search box is not a _descendant_ of your logo to begin with, but only such a constellation is what your selector would match in the first place. Go research how to select elements based on one being a _sibling_ of the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  .vc-headerlogo:hover .vc-searchbox{display:none;}
```

Means that `.vc-searchbox` **nested in** `.vc-headerlogo` will not be displayed when overing `.vc-headerlogo`

In your page, this is not the case: `.vc-searchbox` is not in `.vc-headerlogo`, but **after** (they are sibling). In that case, use the CSS sibling selector **+**

In other words,

```
  .vc-headerlogo:hover+.vc-searchbox{display:none;}
```

should work better

Comment: Thank you, it works! So what if I would like to do the same thing with div class="inner" in footer? Which selector should I use?

Comment: Not possible, footer is totally too far away from `.vc-headerlogo` (if that's the question). Too far away means footer is a sibling of a parent of `.vc-headerlogo`. CSS allows to target descendants or after sibling. CSS does not allow to target parent or previous sibling. You'll have to consider a JS solution in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are open to options, use jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.vc-headerlogo').hover(function(){
  $('.vc-searchbox').hide();
   });
});
```